# Ho to tell if File object points to root directory - android

Tags: java, android

I am working on a basic file browser for a friend and would like to be able to set the action bar/toolbar text to the current working directory.

My problem is as follows: for all folders except root `setTitle(dir.getName())` works. However, when the file represents root ("/") i get some random trash and nothing gets shown in the title bar. For example: `[ 05-16 23:05:15.420  1270: 1270 I/SBar.MotoNetworkCtrlr ] updateDataIcon[0]: mCurrentDataSubId=-1000 maps to: dataPhoneId:0 ( SubscriptionManager.getPhoneId returned -1000=0xfffffc18 )`. Is there any way for me to know if the File object is pointing to root so i can just have it display "/" with a if statement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: need more details -- what platform, language, framework are you using?

Comment: I am using the android SDK and java language

Comment: I don't have accesses to File.getPath() because of androids Java SDK limits